# Sequence $a_n$ which doesn't converge but $a_n^2-4a_n$ converges to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm looking for a sequence $(a_n)_{n∈\mathbb{N}+}$ which does not converge but $a_n^2-4a_n$ converges to 0. I tried looking at trigonometric functions and functions of the form $(-1)^n$, but none of them seem to fit the criteria. Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: For what values of $x$ is $x^2 - 4x = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Notice that $a_n^2-4a_n=a_n(a_n-4)$; can you find a sequence that takes exactly two values in such a way that $a_n^2-4a_n$ converges?

Comment: The limit of $a_n=0$ and the limit of $a_n-4=0$? But in that case $a_n$ converges to $0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @aL_eX: No, make the sequence alternate between two different values.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing that is by using $a_n=(-1)^n$

Comment: @aL_eX: You don’t have to have a formula! If $c$ and $d$ are the two values in question, you can, for instance, let $a_n=c$ if $n$ is even and $a_n=d$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Oh, I see now. You make $a_n=0$ for even values of n, and $a_n=4$ for odd values of n. That way $a_n^2-4a_n$ will tend to 0 wether n is odd or even. Thanks!

Comment: @aL_eX: Yep, you’ve got it. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_{2n}=0$ and $a_{2n+1}=4$.